# Why does the government allow Sabu to roam freely?

Tags: chacha-chaudhary, diamond-comics

In *Chacha Chaudhary* comics, Sabu roam freely with Chacha Chaudhary. Why does government allow this alien from Jupiter to remain on Earth and roam freely? Sabu can hurt someone easily. And, in fact, he does hurt criminals on the command of Chacha Chaudhary. By doing so, he also breaks the laws. Why haven't government acted against it yet?

Comment: Is that you, Mulder? :)

Answer (score 3):

In the diamond comics universe Chacha Chaudhary is very well respected person. Even policemen and politicians respect him. It's never made clear whether police know that Sabu is an alien. Sabu also has a good reputation, so why catch him? He looks like a giant, not like an alien. So maybe most of the people don't know that he is an alien. And he is living with Chacha who is a well reputed person. So the police feel there is no need for capturing Sabu.